# C Array passed to a function: how to absolutely prevent it from being written?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, constants

I would like to prevent an array of integer passed to a function from being altered : use of const

- prevent from being affected (= or ++ : compile error = OK)
- do not prevent from being scanned ! (scanf : only warnings from the compiler...how to get compile error...

Is there a way to do that ?

**EDIT 1: may be I was not clear enough...I would like to demonstrate that, when adding const, it is impossible to modify the content of the array...but it seems that it is not impossible...**

**EDIT 2: conlusion from your answers : with C, it is impossible to prevent an array of integer passed to a function from being modified inside that function (-Wall compiler option produce an error instead of warning)**

I have read things about the placement of const but it does not help me.

Thanks for help.

Example of code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define mySIZE 4

void testReadOnly1(const int t[])
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<mySIZE; i++)
    {
      /*t[i] = 0;*/ /* ERROR : assignment to read-only location */
    }
}
void testReadOnly2(const int t[])
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<mySIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
        scanf("%d",&t[i]); /* warning : writing into constant object */
    }
}
void testReadOnly3(const int const t[])
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<mySIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
        scanf("%d",&t[i]); /* warning : writing into constant object */
    }
}
 void show(const int t[])
 {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i<mySIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",t[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
int main ( void )
{
    int t[mySIZE];
   /*testReadOnly1(t);
        show(t);*/
    testReadOnly2(t);
        show(t);
    testReadOnly3(t);
        show(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to eat the cake and have it.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I stub my toe."

Comment: I only want to look at the cake, but not to eat it ! ;-)

Comment: Please verify: with `foo(int *p) { *p = 0; scanf("%d", p); }`, you want `*p = 0` to fail/warn at compilation, yet have `scanf("%d", p);` with no warnings/errors?

Comment: @chux yes, with =,++, it's ok, but with scanf I have got a warning, but i would like an error

Comment: Really think there is no good way to do this.  Perhaps if you appended the reasons for this need (the higher level issue), a good answer could be posted.

Comment: EDIT : may be I was not clear enough...I would like to demonstrate that, when adding const, it is impossible to modify the content of the array...but it seems that it is not impossible...or get an easy way to do that

Comment: When adding `const`, a good compiler _does_ warn that code is attempting to modify.  Why is wrong with using `testReadOnly2(const int t[])`?  `scanf("%d",&t[i]);` _should_ warn.  **Why** do you want `scanf("%d",&t[i]);` to not warn?

Comment: @chux I think he wants it to be an error.

Comment: The warning is because you are passing the address of a const into scanf whose signature is expecting the address of a non-const. the same would happen for any function you used. the compiler might not actually know that "scanf" is going to try to write to the variable; it only knows (from the signature) that it MIGHT try to change the value - hence the warning instead of error.

Comment: @Weather Vane As many compilers have the option to treat warnings as errors, OP should activate that compiler's option.

Comment: @chux i would like to get a compile error. I am working with Mingw (gcc4.7), with code::blocks, with options : -Wall -Wextra -pedantic...sorry, it seems to come from my english...

Comment: Maybe add `-Werror` and `-pedantic-errors`? (gcc options)

Comment: yes -Werror did it, but I thought (and i would prefer) that  there was a good C language way to do it, as const does it sometimes... So it is impossible to prevent data from being modified with C...Thanks for your help !

Comment: @FredK, ok, i understand why it is only a warning...thanks !

Comment: Do not post answers in your own question.  Instead post your answer below, just like the rest of us.

Comment: Title "C - Array of integer passed to a function : prevent from scanf" could use clarity.  Maybe  "Array passed to a function: how to absolutely prevent it from being written?"

Comment: Conlusion from your answers : with C, it is impossible to prevent an array of integer passed to a function from being modified inside that function (-Wall compiler option can help as it produces an error instead of a warning);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` is a variadic function, `int scanf(const char *restrict format, ...);`, and lacks any type information about the additional parameters that you pass into it.  C compilers these days do have knowledge of printf/scanf-like behavior, and can try to perform some type-checking, like the warning that you get when passing a const object to scanf.  I don't see a way of making the specific `warning : writing into constant object` GCC warning into an error without making all warnings into errors with `-Werror`, even though modifying a const object like this is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks. So calling a function is based on confidence. When you pass a "const" array parameter (by address), you only suppose that the function will not modify values.